# create instances of the class by using different constructors

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, constructor

I have a homework problem which I don't quite understand.

> Add three constructors to the class Critter. Each constructor should
>   also print a simple informational message on the screen such that one
>   can see when and which constructor has been called. You should be able
>   to create an instance of the Critter class 1) without supplying any
>   properties (which should set the name to “default critter”, the height
>   to 5 and the rest to 0), 2) by only supplying a name as parameter
>   (which should set the height to 5 and the rest to 0), and also 3) by
>   supplying name, hunger, boredom and height all as parameters. You
>   should also be able to create an instance of the Critter class without
>   specifying the height. If the height is not supplied, the critter has
>   the default height of 10. Write a test program which creates four
>   instances of the Critter by using these three different constructors
>   (the last one in two ways). Set their hunger levels to 2 by using
>   appropriate method and/or constructor calls. The critters’ properties
>   should then be printed on the screen.

Okay, so first I created a class `Critter` then I added 3 constructors in it as it is described in the points 1, 2 and 3. Then I created an object or instance(they are the same thing right?). After that I created another object and created another constructor. The problem is, I am lost at the last 3 sentences:

> > Write a test program which creates four
> >     instances of the Critter by using these three different constructors
> >     (the last one in two ways). Set their hunger levels to 2 by using
> >     appropriate method and/or constructor calls. The critters’ properties
> >     should then be printed on the screen.

How do I create 4 instances of the Critter by using those three different constructors?

This may sound like a dumb question, but I have never worked before with classes. I am a fan of procedural programming.

---

This is my code:

*Critter.h*

```
class Critter {

    // The following data members are private
    private:
        std::string name;
        int hunger, boredom;
        double height;

    public:

        Critter();
        Critter(std::string& newname);
        Critter(std::string& newname, int newhunger, int newboredom, double newheight);
        Critter(std::string& newname, int newhunger, int newboredom);

};
```

and in another file I wrote:

*Critter.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Critter.h"

using namespace std;

Critter::Critter() {
    name = "default critter";
    height = 5.0;
    hunger = 0;
    boredom = 0;
    cout << "First with no properties." << endl;
}

Critter::Critter(string& newname) {
    name = newname;
    height = 5.0;
    hunger = 0;
    boredom = 0;
  cout << "Only name as a parameter." << endl;
}

Critter::Critter(string& newname, int newhunger, int newboredom, double newheight) {
    name = newname;
    height = newheight;
    hunger = newhunger;
    boredom = newboredom;
  cout << "All as parameters." << endl;
}

Critter::Critter(string& newname, int newhunger, int newboredom) {
    name = newname;
    height = 10.0;
    hunger = newhunger;
    boredom = newboredom;
  cout << "All as parameters." << endl;
}
```

and the main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Critter.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Critter first_instance, second_instance;

    string name;
    int hunger, boredom;
    double height;


    return 0;
}
```

Looking forward to your suggestions/answers.

Thank you

Comment: Example: `Critter second_instance{"bob", 0, 0, 3.0};`   . This creates an instance using the constructor `Critter(string& newname, int newhunger, int newboredom, double newheight))`

Comment: `Critter(std::string& newname, int newhunger, int newboredom);` was not a part of the request - there's supposed to be a total of 3 constructors (the other three you have written)

Comment: @M.M so that means i need to create just one object and call those constructors 4 times? Thanks

Comment: No, you need to create 4 objects.  It's only possible to call a constructor once per object:  "call the constructor" is a synonym for "create an object".

Comment: @M.M Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created 4 constructors, but they want you to have 3, the last of which should be used in 2 ways. The first two are fine, what they want you to do is to merge your third and fourth constructor into a single one by using [default arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) for functions. Like this:

```
Critter::Critter(string& newname, int newhunger, int newboredom, double newheight = 10.0) {
    name = newname;
    height = newheight;
    hunger = newhunger;
    boredom = newboredom;
  cout << "All as parameters." << endl;
}
```

This way it's a single constructor, but you can call it in two ways:

1. either with all the arguments, including `newheight`, or
2. by providing only the first three, and then `newheight` will have the
   default value of 10.0.

**EDIT** to answer the question in a comment:

How do you create 4 instances using these 3 constructors?

The line

```
Critter my_first_critter;
```

will create an object of class Critter called `my_first_critter`, with no arguments, which means that the compiler will select the first constructor, and you'll read "First with no properties.". Instead, a line like

```
Critter my_second_critter("John");
```

will create a new object of class Critter, called `my_second_critter`, and since there's a string argument the compiler will select the second constructor, so that you'll read "Only name as a parameter.". Then, a line like

```
Critter my_third_critter("James", 2, 3, 5.5);
```

(notice the fourth argument!) will create one more object, again of class Critter and called `my_third_critter`, and since there are four arguments, of type: string, int, int, double, the compiler will call the third constructor and you'll read "All as parameters.". Finally, a line like

```
Critter my_fourth_critter("Peter", 2, 3);
```

(notice the fourth argument is missing!) will call the same function, because in this case the default argument kicks in. The compiler will still match this call to the third constructor (so that you will read, again, "All as parameters."), but in this case the height will be the default value of 10.0, as the programmer that created the object (you) didn't specify the value.

Setting the default value of height to 10.0 is useful if it happens very often that the height is 10.0 and you don't want to waste time specifying this number every time you create a `Critter` (which would also be error-prone: think of typos or getting confused...). Still, if you need a value other than 10.0, you can easily provide it. And since it's just one constructor, and not 2 separate ones, you have less code to manage. You could, of course, avoid using default arguments and write 2 constructors (as you have done), but suppose you find a bug in your third one: most certainly you'd have to fix it in your fourth one as well. What if you forget to do it? If you have just one function your code is easier to manage. Also, consider that you can provide more than one default argument per function. If you had to do without default arguments, you'd have to create a lot of copies. It wouldn't scale well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have another question, the problem says to create four instances, but I don't understand why and how to do that; or maybe I don't understand what that request means.

Comment: @zeeks I have edited my answer to address your question.

Comment: @M.M Damn, most vexing parse again. Thank you, I have fixed it!